# Grouping Negates Effect of \centering

Tags: spacing, grouping

Why does the use of `\begingroup`, `\endgroup` negate the effect of centering in the MWE?

The MWE below yields a left aligned figure (*not* desired), with subsequent text on the left (*desired*):

[image]

But if I remove the `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`, then things work as desired as far as the `\centering` goes, but then the subsequent text is also centered?

[image]

### Question:

- I thought the entire purpose of grouping was to localize the effect. So, what is the subtlety of grouping that results in this behavior?
- How do I keep the grouping, yet also have the centering?  I would like to ensure that any settings that are changed via the inserted figure are kept local to that figure.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented to prevent overwriting myFig.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{myFig.tex}
    \def\YLabel{$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel=\YLabel]
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4}; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\InsertFigure}[1]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}{%
        \begingroup%
            \centering%
            \input{#1}%
        \endgroup%
    }{}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \InsertFigure{myFig.tex}

\textbf{Text on left.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to end the paragraph before closing the group (`\centering` and other similar commands as well as font size switches (`\small`, `\large`, `\Huge`, etc.), need to "see" an end of paragraph to work correctly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented to prevent overwriting myFig.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{myFig.tex}
    \def\YLabel{$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel=\YLabel]
        \addplot {x^2 - x +4}; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\InsertFigure}[1]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}{%
        \begingroup%
            \centering%
            \input{#1}\par%
        \endgroup%
    }{}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \InsertFigure{myFig.tex}

\textbf{Text on left.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well that was easy!! Can't believe I forgot to try that!!

Comment: I guess what you mean by "font switches" is rather a use of something just as `\small` or `\Large` and the effect on `\baselineskip`? because I don't see offhand (except in math mode) other "font switches" that need to see the end of the paragraph (resp. math mode) to work correctly.

Comment: @jfbu yes Gonzalo means the font size commands here which as you say will change the font but mess up the baseline spacing if used this way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah ok. And I probably should add, regarding math mode, that I was not thinking of any LaTeX `user` level command but of the fact that TeX uses in the entire formula the font families as defined at the end of the math mode.

Comment: @jfbu yes, as David mentioned, I meant those size switches. I edited my answer to make that clear.